# MQTT IOS cannot send message to the Raspberry pi

Tags: ios, cocoapods, mqtt, mosquitto

I am developing an app to send messages to my Raspberry pi. I have done the code in XCode and a python script on the Raspberry Pi. The connection between iOS and Raspberry Pi using MQTT shows that it works. In the Raspberry pi, I am using mosquitto MQTT server. And for the App, I am using Cocoapods. My issue is that when I pressed the button to send a message. The message is not received on the Raspberry Pi even though the app is connected to it.

Below, it is the code for the App using Xcode. It is a simple code just to prove the concept.

```
import UIKit
import CocoaMQTT

class ViewController: UIViewController {

var direction = "forward"
//Instantiate CocoaMQTT as mqttClient
let mqttClient = CocoaMQTT(clientID: "iosApp", host: "192.168.1.22", port: 1883)

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
}

@IBAction func connectBtnPressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.connect()
    print("Connection establish")
}

@IBAction func picturePressed(_ sender: UIButton) {
    mqttClient.publish("rover/move", withString: "picture")
}
}
```

Python script code:

```
import paho.mqtt.client as mqtt

clientName = "rover"
serverAddress = "192.168.1.22"
mqttClient = mqtt.Client(clientName)

def connectionStatus(client, userdata, flags, rc):
    print("subscribing")
    mqttClient.subscribe("rover/move")
    print("subscribed")

def messageDecoder(client, userdata, msg):
    message = msg.payload.decode(encoding='UTF-8')

   if message == "picture":
      file1 = open("passchar.txt","a")
      file1.seek(0)
      file1.truncate()
      file1.write("c")
      file1.close()
      print("Pic time")
   else:
      print("?!? Unknown message?!?")

# Set up calling functions to mqttClient
mqttClient.on_connect = connectionStatus
mqttClient.on_message = messageDecoder

# Connect to the MQTT server & loop forever.
mqttClient.connect(serverAddress)
mqttClient.loop_forever()
```

The output I get in the Raspberry pi

[image: Output which shows the connection between IOS App and Raspberry Pi]

I pressed on my app the button for picture but it does not show that the message was received.

Comment: Please do not post pictures of text, post the actual text and use the tool bar to format it. It is impossible to search for text in images.

Comment: Have you verified that `picturePressed` is being called (using a print statement or a breakpoint)?

Comment: @Paulw11 yes, I did. The button is being called on the Xcode, but the Raspberry Pi does not receive the message.

Comment: Seems pretty obvious that your Xcode app is not publishing the MQTT packet. We see it connect in the Mosquitto log, so we know that part is working...but your picturePressed() is not firing. You sure you have defined the 'picture' object correctly??  You say it is being called, but that doesn't seem to be what is happening.  If you are sure you are calling the function, then your MQTT library is mess up or installed incorrectly, and magically, the connect() function still works, but the publish() function sadly does not.

Comment: @JDAllen So, I put a print statement in the picturePressed function under publish. So, in the output window of Xcode shows :                                                 
        Connection establish
        Picture button has been pressed.
        Picture button has been pressed.
        Message from debugger: Terminated due to signal 9

Comment: So signal 9 is SIGKILL....something in your MQTT library caused (I am guessing here since I don't do iOS programming) the iOS Kernel to kill the program for some reason. In other *inux OS's, this usually means it tried to grab memory from some place it should not, or it otherwise was stepping on something it should not be.  You might want to remove the library and reinstall, unless someone who knows more about iOS has a better idea ;)

Comment: @JDAllen Ok I will try that again. I did uninstall cocoapods and reinstall but I faced the same. Terminated due to signal 9 is when I closed the app simulator. But, I am gonna give it a try again and let's see my luck.